# htaccess, adding rules for each domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a hosting account that has multiple domains pointed to the same folder. In this folder I have an htaccess file. I need to know how I can write rules for only specific domains, so if I wrote a rewrite rule for one domain pointed to the folder that rule wont be used for the other domains pointed to the folder. I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
# Domain1.com Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1 /page1.php [L]

# Domain2.com Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page2 /page2.php [L]
```

When I say it doesnt work, when I go to page2 from domain1.com, domain1.com/page2, then the page2 rewrite rule for domain2.com works. But I dont want it to work, I only want page2 rule to only work when someone comes to the site under domain2.com. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Domain1.com Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page2(\.php)?/?$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^page1 page1.php [L]

# Domain2.com Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1(\.php)?/?$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^page2 page2.php [L]
```

Comment: What if I have numerous domains with numerous links that need to be broken out for each domain? Is this not possible in htaccess? Do I need to edit the apache conf file for each domain?

Comment: everything is possible. This answer is based on your OP, can you give me examples, this would help me figure out what you need to do.

Comment: @ Book Of Zeus Well its hard to give a specific example. Basically I have a web app in php that sits in one directory on a cpanel server. I have 20 domains pointed to this one folder. What I wanted to do is use the htaccess file to load any redirect/rewrite rules based on the domain in the url. One site I want a rule to do a url rewrite but it only loads for that specific domain and wont be rewritten for any other domain. It could be hundreds of rewrite rules for just one domain that I dont want the other 19 following.

Comment: My opinion: I'm in the same situation and I use symbolic link to manage all my control panel etc... maybe that will be a better solution (or create one .htaccess and symblink to all the other domains)